# When is it true that $<X,Y> = <<X>><Y>$ for $X$ and $Y$ disjoint subsets of a free group $G = <X, Y>$?

Tags: group-theory

Here $<Y>$ denotes the subgroup generated by $Y$, and $<<X>>$ denotes the normal subgroup generated by $X$, in $G$, where $X$ and $Y$ together form a free basis of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be true.

For any subsets $X,Y$ you have $\langle X,Y\rangle\le\langle\langle X\rangle\rangle\langle Y\rangle$ (as $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is contained in any group containing $X,Y$). Here then $G=\langle X,Y\rangle\le\langle\langle X\rangle\rangle\langle Y\rangle\le G$, hence the result.